# Создать массив элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой вот код:

```
<div id="elements">
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить массив всех элементов `div`, чтобы в последствии можно было обращаться к массивам ссылок?
Как-то так:

```
divs[0]  
links[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `jQuery` работа с массивами скрыта, происходит в "фоновом режиме", если так можно выразиться. То есть следующий код выделит в последнем `div` вторую ссылку зелёной рамкой:

```
$(function(){
    $('#elements div:eq(2) a:eq(1)').css('border', '1px solid green');
});
```

Вопрос слишком размыт. Есть метод `toArray()` (создает и возвращает массив элементов), есть функция `each()` (позволяет "обойти" каждый элемент в выборке и совершить на ними определённые действия - прямая аналогия обхода массива), метод `index('a')` - возвращает индекс элемента в дереве DOM, метод `get(index)` - позволяет обращаться к определённому элементу в дереве DOM...
В общем, мы имеем дело с деревом DOM, везде массивы.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую пояснить.
у меня есть некий список ссылок. Этот список динамический, но разделяется по 5 ссылок. То есть, в элементе div максимум 5 ссылок, если ссылок больше пяти, то создаётся ещё 1 div, и последующие ссылки добавляются уже в него. И так далее.

предположим, мне надо одну из этих ссылок удалить. Но если просто тупо удалить, то в одном из дивов уже не 5 ссылок, а допустим 4.  
Хочу сделать сортировку. то есть, если в где - то в среднем ДИВе будет 4 ссылки, то мы в этот ДИВ забираем одну ссылку из следующего ДИВа, короче, и так далее. )

Comment: если так, то решение мне видется таким: проверяем размерность содержимого нужного div'а методом size(). если размерность меньше 5, берём из следующего div'а ссылку и добавляем её в предыщий div через appendTo().

Comment: кстати, я реализовал эту идею. если ещё интересно - я выложу)

Answer (score 1):

```
var divs = $('#elements div');
```

Выберете 3 div'a

Сможете обратится к ним через divs[0],divs[1],divs[2],

Выбрать а с конкретного дива:

```
var divsa=divs[0].find('a');
```

выбрать первый а - `divsa[0]`.
Как то так:)

Comment: А можно ли как - то получить массив этих ссылок определённого ДИВа?
то есть, чтобы узнать, сколько ссылок в каждом диве?
Просто Ваш совет, почему - то не работает. (

просто, после обращения к массиву дивов, типа: divs[0] - код сразу перестаёт работать.

Comment: Почитайте про слекторы jQuery и про функцию each в js, думаю после этого все будет понятно

Answer (score 1):

```
function div(div, a) {
    if ('number' === typeof div) {
        var elements = $('#elements'),
                div = $('div', elements).get(div);
        if ('number' === typeof a) {
            return $('a', div).get(a);
        }
        return div;
    }
}
```

Индексы начинаются с 0...

```
console.log(div(0)); // получаем первый див со всеми ссылками
console.log(div(1, 1)); // получаем 2 див и 2 ссылку
```

и т.д.

Answer (score -2):

В `jQuery` методе [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) пишешь функцию, которая возвращает именно массив из выбранных элементов или узлов.
Очень удобно.